# What does the scalpel-shaped icon in the gutter in Visual Studio 2008 mean?

Tags: visual-studio, icons

What does this icon mean?

[image: Visual Studio scalpel icon in the gutter]

It doesn’t seem to have a tooltip, it doesn’t respond on right-click, and it doesn’t seem to want to disappear either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It shows Find All results. (Possibly other things too!)

Edit to clarify: when you double-click an entry in a Find Results panel, the "scalpel" shows up next to the relevant line of code. Helps you pick it out by eye, I guess, as the cursor may not be very noticeable.

Further edit: [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/zd665bbb(v=vs.100).aspx) says *To jump to a match, double-click any line in the results list. The source file is displayed in the Code Editor with the insertion point placed where the matched text begins. A symbol appears in the indicator margin of the Editor to mark the line that includes the match, and the status bar displays its full text.* - as they don't name it I doubt the symbol is used elsewhere.